# I want to show each product with the sum(total) quantity Which they sold out

Tags: mysql

i have table like this

```
date , N°ProDUCT , QUANTIE_SELL
```

[image]

every day i sell pruduct

```
N°pruduct------quantite_sell
```

i want to show eatch pruduct with the sum of the quantite ?

```
exmpl :1----82
       2-----70
       3-----12
```

the sql statment ??

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you show what you have tried. If you haven;t tried anything yet search for mysql aggregate functions.AND include sample data as text in the question which we could use rather than image which we cannot .https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You'd be surprised how little of an effort it will take you to get to the answer if you just research for a minute. Here is some help https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the below query :-

SELECT SUM(quantite_sell) from product GROUP BY Nprod;

Thanks

Comment: You need to include the product in the select to get the result desired by the OP

Comment: hi , this is for show just the summ of the quantite , i need the Nprod+quantite sum, like this : 1==59 ect.....

Comment: this is work :[SELECT SUM(quantite_sell),Nprod from product GROUP BY Nprod;